# How do I make Material UI container have full width and height?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to wrap a page in a React project in a Material UI container but it squeezes in all my content with these weird margins. Here is what it looks like: [image]

But I want it to look like this with full width: [image]

Haven't been able to find any other resources explaining how to change the width of the container. Does anyone have any workarounds? I tried adjusting the width of the container to be 100vw but it was unresponsive to my CSS. Here is my code:

```html
////BUY PAGE

import React from 'react';

import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import AppBar from '../../components/AppBar/AppBar';
import Footer from '../../components/Footer/Footer';

import './Buy.css';

const Buy = () => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <AppBar />
            <Footer />
        </Container>
    );
};

export default Buy;
```

```css
////CSS

.buy-container {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 43):

You should be able to get the results you're looking for by setting the `maxWidth` property of `Container` to false e.g:

```
<Container maxWidth={false}>
  <AppBar />
  <Footer />
</Container>
```

The `maxWidth` property determines the `max-width` of the container. The container width grows with the size of the screen. By setting it to *false* you can disable the `maxWidth` property.

[MUI `Container`](https://mui.com/api/container/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31157547)

Answer (score 12):

You will need to add `maxWidth={false}` and `disableGutters` properties to the `<Container/>` component. Additionally, you should include the `<CssBaseline/>` component to reset the browser's CSS.

### Example:

```
<>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Container maxWidth={false} disableGutters>
      {children}
    </Container>
</>
```

### Container API

| Name | Type | Default | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| maxWidth | 'xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl', false, string |  | Determine the max-width of the container. The container width grows with the size of the screen. Set to `false` to disable `maxWidth`. |
| disableGutters | bool | false | If `true`, the left and right padding is removed. |

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid to set the custom container width until changing the breakpoints.

Otherwise, you can use a custom div element or [Box](https://mui.com/components/box/) component.

```
// makeStyles
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    height: '100%',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: '100%'
  },
}));

// styled
const LayoutContainer = styled('div')(() => ({
  height: '100%',
  overflow: 'hidden',
  width: '100%'
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `<Container>` within `<Box>`/`<Appbar>` that has the background color e.g:

```
<Box sx={{ bgcolor: 'black'}}>
  <Container>
    My content
  </Container>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at global css variables to overwrite the standard ([see here](https://mui.com/guides/interoperability/#global-css)):

The material docs suggest this way or using styling overrides which may be another option for you.

```css
.MuiContainer-root {
  width: 100vw;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

FYI - I got the global css name from the [Container portion of the docs](https://mui.com/api/container/) under "root", in case you've not seen it.

Answer (score -1):

minHeight: '100%' worked for me in that kind of situation

Comment: How is changing the height going to affect width? Please provide more detail on how this work, with example

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).